# How to develop a good web design in web site

Tags: design, development

I have a web development site, but I do better and better design in my site, because I develop a good web site design so please reply me if you know of other ideas.

My website is located at http://www.esparkinfo.com/

Answer (score 3):

I am quite unsure what your question is:

1. You want us to check your website design and give you hints and ideas on what to improve?
2. You want project ideas for website design, so you may go and design them?
3. You want us to check if your skills are up to par and suggest you to work in a different field than website design?

**Answering possible question 1:**

Boy, there is so much wrong with that posted URL, I really don't know where to start. Heard of "TL;DR"? That is what your site is. It's Too Long;Didn't Read. Dramatically reduce the text on your site. Play with white space. You are using way too many fonts. Check font use, they don't seem to fit together. You have too many color variations (green/brown, orange/white, blue/orange, blue/white, orange/white, blue/grey, green/white, the list goes on and on... I suggest you check out sites like *dribbble.com* and others to see where webdesign is heading at.

**Answering possible question 2:**

This is the wrong place to ask this. If you are looking for projects, go check out *crowdspring.com*. Good site to find and bid on cool projects.

**Answering possible question 3:**

Again, this is the wrong place to ask this question. I am sure that you know what you are doing and you really should learn the fine art that is called website design. It often doesn't take much to take an intermediate design and transform it into a great design. Please note, that many successful websites don't "design" their site, but the content they present within their design fits perfectly and makes the website asthetically pleasing to viewers. You don't just design a page and inject words into it. You need to carefully lay out and plan, what you want to say on what page, where it will be shown, how and on what areas you want your readers to focus on. Then you design your site with these in mind.

Comment: +1 For bothering to even attempt to answer a poorly formatted question.